# Process cannot access file error - iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, itext

I have below function using iTextSharp library to create pdfs.

```
    public static string SavePDF(int id, bool isApproved)
    {
        string path = "";
        using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 42, 53, 70, 46))
        {
            PdfHelper page = new PdfHelper();
            path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/File_" + id + ".pdf");

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;

                    doc.Open();
                    //code to add contents to pdf

                    doc.Close();
                    fs.Close(); 
                } 
            } fs.Dispose();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return path;
    }
```

The above function is called twice in a .NET application. However on the second call, it gives me below error:

`System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXXWebsite\Files\File_1605.pdf' because it is being used by another process. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)`

I am quite baffled with this error as i have changed the code many times by including using statement and also Close() and Dispose() the objects. Have even used Threading to wait for operation to complete first, yet I seem to get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as a test *only* can you see how long it takes for the first call to free up the file? (ie use a while loop and try/catch; dont leave this code in there) - or have you already done this and it is never freed until stopping application?

Comment: One thing I noticed - why are you calling `fs.Dispose()` inside your `using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))` block ? You know that `using ()` will call Dispose for you ?

Comment: Is this method called twice _simultaneously_ possibly? If so, a mutex or something similar might help. If you are running on a local machine you could try running [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). I'd also recommend using the more explicit `FileStream` declaration that denies others access, `using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))`

Comment: @ChrisHaas The second call to the method is made after around 10 seconds from first call.

Comment: The only other thing I'd try is swapping the order of your `using` statements. Your `FileStream` should come first, then your `Document` and finally your `PdfWriter`

Comment: @ChrisHaas tried above as well.. Still same error.